# Wix Installer UI Dialogs are tiny on windows 7

Tags: wix

I'm extremely new to Wix and I'm trying to make changes to an existing installer. It seems that on windows seven the installer dialogs are microscopic and therefore it's almost impossible to read the labels or text fields as you perform the installation. Is there a quick way to fix this across all of the UIs?

[image]

It looks fine on Win 2k8 btw

Comment: A screenshot of what you're talking about might help getting the answer :)

Comment: Do you see the same effect with other installers? Could it be a display setting in the OS?

Comment: If it's a display setting that's the issue I would argue that it's a problem with the installer still... I'm using a bog-standard installation of Windows 7 on a Dell Laptop... An for all intents and purposes I would say I have no 'display issues' everything else I use on this computer appears to look the same as my other computers...